# Red error underline position is not correct from Grammarly Chrome extension

Tags: javascript

Before scroll, the red lines are right below the text, [image: the red line is right below the text]

After scroll, the red lines' position are not correct, [image: the red line's position is not correct]

If you continue scroll, the red lines's position will change...

Minimal code to reproduce,

base.py

```
import SocketServer

PORT = 8081

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<style>
html,body {
height: 200%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
ert wer ttt 
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using macbook pro, and just run `python2 base.py`, and open `http://0.0.0.0:8081/base.html`

Currently I disabled the extension using `data-gramm="false"`

Comment: Sounds like something you should report to the extension's authors, not here.

Comment: @wOxxOm Already reported, since it's not an open source project, I only got some useless reply from their support team(non-technical).

Comment: I mean anyone can provide a `workaround` solution?

Comment: Someone will have to debug the extension. Almost invariably the best person to do that is the author.